# xpath looping to unknown number of nodes

Tags: php, xpath, html-parsing

I've a xpath that looks like this:

```
$path = '//*[@id="page-content"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td['.$i.']/div/a';
```

where `$i` goes from 1 to **X**. I would normaly use:

```
for($i=1; $i<X;$i++){
  $path = '//*[@id="page-content"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td['.$i.']/div/a';
  $nodelist = $xpath->query($path);
  $result = $nodelist->item(0)->nodeValue;
};
```

However, in this case, I dont know how much is **X**. Is there any way to loop through this without knowing X?

Comment: i'm not sure I understand your question. Your for() loop is already looping up to 'X' times, regardless if you know the value there. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question, you're asking how to loop up until the max number of `<td>` elements under your XPath?

You could retrieve the number of nodes using:

`count(//*[@id="page-content"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td)` and store it as a temp variable, then just use it in your next statement like so:

```
for($i=1; $i<numberOfTdElements;$i++){
  $path = '//*[@id="page-content"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td['.$i.']/div/a';
  $nodelist = $xpath->query($path);
  $result = $nodelist->item(0)->nodeValue;
};
```

In response to hakre's suggestion:

```
$tbody = $doc->getElementsByTagName('tbody')->item(0);

// our query is relative to the tbody node
$query = 'count(tr[3]/td)';

$tdcount = $xpath->evaluate($query, $tbody);
echo "There are $tdcount elements under tr[3]\n";
```

And then combine it all in:

```
for($i=1; $i<$tdcount;$i++){
      $path = '//*[@id="page-content"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td['.$i.']/div/a';
      $nodelist = $xpath->query($path);
      $result = $nodelist->item(0)->nodeValue;
    };
```

Comment: Nice idea, too. You might want to show how the count can be returned via [`DOMXPath::evaluate`](http://php.net/domxpath.evaluate), too.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just stack em? Something like (fragile code, add your checks):

```
// first xpath for the outer node-list
$tds = $xpath->query('//*[@id="page-content"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td');
foreach ($tds as $td)
{
    // fetch the included values with a relative xpath to the current node
    $nodelist = $xpath->query('./div/a', $td);
    ...
}
```

And actually you wont even need that inner nodelist, because you want to query the node-values in the end. However I leave this here to show what you can do straight ahead by using an xpath relative to a concrete node.

---

So if you need the *first* `<a>` element inside *any* `<div>` inside the *third* `<tr>` of *any* table inside of *any* node with the id *"page-content"*, you can write it as such directly, it is one query:

```
//*[@id="page-content"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/a[1]
```

The predicate (that are the brackets) is only for the node in the path prefixed to it, so the `[1]` is only for `a` at the end as was the `[3]` only for the `tr`.

Code Example:

```
$as = $xpath->query('//*[@id="page-content"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/a[1]');
foreach ($as as $a) 
{
    echo $a->nodeValue, "\n";
}
```

So this would give you the result as a single node-list, you do not need to run a second xpath query.

Comment: I like yours better, more elegant/cleaner. +1

Comment: @MichaelKay I agree. Maybe he chose that answer because it required the least change to his current code, which was my intention.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is fetch every `a` element that is a child of a `div`, which in its turn is a child of any `td` element that, in its turn, is a child of every *third* `tr` element, etc. If that is correct, you can simply fetch these with this query:

```
<?php 

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML( $xml );
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $doc );
$nodes = $xpath->query( '//*[@id="page-content"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/a' );
foreach( $nodes as $node )
{
    echo $node->nodeValue . '<br>';
}
```

Where `$xml` is a document, similar to this:

```
<?php

$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<result>
    <div id="page-content">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div><a>This one shouldn't be fetched</a></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div><a>This one shouldn't be fetched</a></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div><a>This one should be fetched</a></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div><a>This one should be fetched</a></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div><a>This one should be fetched</a></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div><a>This one should be fetched</a></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div><a>This one should be fetched</a></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div><a>This one shouldn't be fetched</a></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</result>
XML;
```

In other words, no need to loop trough all these `td` elements. You can fetch them all in one go, resulting in a `DOMNodeList` with all required nodes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();

$doc->loadXML( $xml );

$xpath = new DOMXPath( $doc );

$nodes = $xpath->query( '/result/div[@id="page-content"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/a');

foreach( $nodes as $node )
{
    echo $node->nodeValue . '<br>';
}
```